# SQL join only if there is no match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a (postgres) sql table that has the following contents (Hosts):

```
   ip_address   |  mac_address   | hostname | device | physical_port
----------------+----------------+----------+--------+---------------
111.111.111.111 | aaaa.aaaa.aaaa | hosta    | swh-a  | Gi1/1
111.111.111.112 | bbbb.bbbb.bbbb | hostb    | swh-b  | Gi2/1
111.111.111.113 | cccc.cccc.cccc | hostc    | swh-c  | Gi3/1
```

I have another table (Peers) that contains point-to-point links between `devices` in the able table.

```
 device | physical_port | peer_device | peer_physical_port 
 -------+---------------+-------------+----------------------+
 swh-a  | Gi1/20        | swh-b       | Gi2/1
 swh-b  | Gi2/1         | swh-a       | Gi1/20
 swh-b  | Gi2/1         | swh-c       | Gi3/1
 swh-c  | Gi3/1         | swh-b       | Gi2/1
```

Basically, I would like the **exclude** entries from the Hosts table that are contained within the Peers table such that I only get:

```
   ip_address   |  mac_address   | hostname | device | physical_port
----------------+----------------+----------+--------+---------------
111.111.111.111 | aaaa.aaaa.aaaa | hosta    | swh-a  | Gi1/1
```

(given that `device=swh-b physical_port=Gi2/1` and `device=swh-c physical_port=Gi3/1` exist within the Peers table).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for a self-explanatory query that reads almost as if it were in English:

```
SELECT *
FROM Hosts h
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Peers p
    WHERE p.peer_device = h.device AND p.peer_physical_port = h.physical_port
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT * FROM Hosts
WHERE NOT peer_physical_port IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT peer_physical_port FROM Peers
)
```

You are selecting only the entries that do not appear in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Host h
LEFT JOIN Peers p ON p.device= h.device and p.physical_port = h.physical_port
WHERE p.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Host
WHERE   device NOT IN (SELECT device FROM Peers )
AND     physical_port NOT IN (SELECT physical_port FROM Peers)
```